# Drupal translate module doesn't work for HTML <img> tag

Tags: drupal, translation

As said in the title, I want to make some images to vary depending on the user language. The thing is Drupal doesn't allow the tag  in the translation form. What can I do to make it work ?

Answer (score 0):

Do it using [`$language` global variable](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--globals.php/global/language/7). [`t()` function](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--bootstrap.inc/function/t/7) is meant for text visible to the user.

You can use it (`$language` global variable) in theme, or even within block / page, if PHP filter is enabled for theme.

Answer (score 0):

As **Tadeck** proposed, you should use $language variable instead.
Should look like this:

```
global $language;
print '<img src="path-to-image-/my-img-{$language->language}.jpg" alt="" />';
```

In this case you should have images with the names like:

```
my-img-en.jpg
my-img-fr.jpg
my-img-it.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Drupal 7, you can try out [this module](http://drupal.org/project/i18n_media) where you put your images, videos, etc.

So they are localized like:

```
/en/my-image.png
/fr/my-image.png
/de/my-image.png
```

and it will be smart about choosing the correct one.

Answer (score -1):

try leaving out the initial img tag and see  if the t function works I had read in a post.

```
$output= '<img>'. t("src='1.jpg'>This is a trial<img> ");
```